# Video's sharing through Pinterest in iPhone using Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, video, xamarin, pinterest

I need to share videos through Pinterest from my App.
I am able to share images using [this website](https://components.xamarin.com/view/pinterestsdk)
but I need to share video's through Pinterest.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the component [Xamarin.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth) to be able to login to Pinterest
- Create an App on https://developers.pinterest.com/ for the login and read how the  API works in order to be able to communicate with pinterest and share a video
- For example see something like this implemented on Xamarin for [Twitter](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/using-oauth-twitter-and-async-to-display-data.aspx)